# Finding different max between specified rows of different fields

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I'm looking to find the max values of different columns based on specified rows of each column.

My actual data frame is 50K columns and 1K+ rows so I can't use a loop without greatly increasing run time.

Data Frame:

| row | V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 | 3 | 2 | 6 |
| 4 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 10 |
| 5 | 6 | 9 | 1 | 2 |

```
beg_row <- c(2, 1, 2, 3)
end_row <- c(4, 3, 3, 5)
```

output:

```
c(7, 5, 2, 10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `mapply` (but I suspect that it won't speed up the runtime if you have massive columns)

```
> mapply(function(x, y, z) max(x[y:z]), df[-1], beg_row, end_row)
V1 V2 V3 V4
 7  5  2 10
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(row = 1:5, V1 = c(5L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 6L), V2 = c(
  2L,
  5L, 3L, 5L, 9L
), V3 = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), V4 = c(
  5L, 6L, 6L,
  10L, 2L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

beg_row <- c(2, 1, 2, 3)

end_row <- c(4, 3, 3, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  summarise(across(-row, ~ {
   i1 <- match(cur_column(), names(df1)[-1])
     max(.x[beg_row[i1]:end_row[i1]])}))
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  7  5  2 10
```

---

Or another option is to create `NA` outside the range and then use `colMaxs`

```
library(matrixStats)
colMaxs(as.matrix((NA^!(row(df1[-1]) >= beg_row[col(df1[-1])] & 
    row(df1[-1]) <= end_row[col(df1[-1])])) * df1[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)
[1]  7  5  2 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest approach that I have found is to use `data.table` and a `for` loop. I have tested it with a dataframe of 2K rows and 50K columns.

```r
library(data.table)

beg_row <- sample(1:50, 49999, replace = T)
end_row <- sample(100:150, 49999, replace = T)

df <- matrix(sample(1:50, 50000*2000, replace = T), 2000, 50000)
df <- as.data.frame(df)

dt <- setDT(df)

vmax <- rep(0, ncol(dt)-1)

for (i in 2:ncol(dt)) {
  vmax[i-1] <- max(dt[[i]][beg_row[i-1]:end_row[i-1]])
}
```

---

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::pmap_dbl`:

```r
library(purrr)

pmap_dbl(list(beg_row, end_row, 2:ncol(df)), ~ max(df[..1:..2, ..3]))

#> [1]  7  5  2 10
```